# Run script if screen size greater than value

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a home page which has a basic image fader:

```
<div id="cycle">
    <img src="/images/bath.jpg">
    <img src="/images/desk.jpg">
    <img src="/images/car.jpg">
</div>
```

At the foot of the document I've got some jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if ($(window).width() > 480) {
        $('#cycle').fadeIn(4000).cycle({
            timeout: 8000,
            speed: 4000
        }); 
    }
});
```

So, I only want this script to run if the screen width is greater than 480px on load. Is this the best way of doing that? I guess I could hide the `.cycle` div using media queries, but I don't then want the script doing its thing in the background.

Is the only way to have the `.cycle` div fade in on resize to use:

```
$(window).resize(function() {});
```

?

Comment: Best way to do it? Dunno, good enough? Yeah. If `$(window).resize...` work, why don't you simply use it? It's what I'd do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would something like this work for you. Here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ae5w/1/show/) ... [fiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ae5w/1/)

```
function checkSize(){
    if ($(window).width() > 480) {
        cycleImages();
    }else{
        $('#cycle').fadeOut().cycle('stop');
    }
}

function cycleImages(){
    $('#cycle').fadeIn(4000).cycle({
        timeout: 8000,
        speed: 4000
    }); 
}

checkSize();

$(window).resize(function() {
    checkSize();
});
```

Comment: Nice. My concern with resize() was laggy performance when resizing, but I guess if checkSize() only fires when the condition is met, it shouldn't make much of an impact. BTW how come you created a separate fn for cycleImages() - just to make things more organised?

Comment: Yea, to keep it organized and so that i don't duplicate the code (once for load and once for resize)